# "scene in" vs "scene from"

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

Do we say "best scene in the movie" or "best scene from the movie"? I feel like both are grammatical and idiomatic, but the second phrasing sounds better, but I was wondering if both were completely valid phrases.

For example:

> It's the best scene in the movie.
>
> It's the best scene in this underrated movie.
>
> Best scene in the most underrated movie of the year by far!

Comment: If you're making a more "abstract" reference to a scene that only "exists" *within its actual context as part of the movie*, it's usually more natural to use the standard "container" metaphor (with ***in***). If your context is one where you've just shown (or been presented with) *just that actual scene, not as **part** of watching the entire movie*, the "locational, place of origin" metaphoric usage (with preposition ***from***) is usually more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a movie with someone, then "in the movie" and "from the movie" are pretty interchangeable.

If you're watching a movie review program and they show one of the movie's scenes, "from" is used much more than "in":

> Here is a clip **from** the movie.

This is because to show the clip, they've had to take it "**out**" of the movie, so it's no longer **in** the context of the whole movie.

If you are talking about an actor in real life or in another movie or show, you can say:

> That's Pat Jones **from** movie X.

So it's about the context. If the context is the whole movie, use "in". If the context is a small part of the movie, or outside the movie, use "from".

When you say "best" in conversation, you're usually referring to the whole movie, so:

> It's the best scene **in** the movie.

although

> It's the best scene **from** the movie.

is also perfectly acceptable.

[image]

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+in+the+movie%2C*+from+the+movie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C*%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscene%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brole%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bused%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpart%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscenes%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpeople%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscene%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscenes%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baway%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhome%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsong%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bline%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btheme%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btaken%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstills%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscene%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brole%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bused%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpart%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscenes%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpeople%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20in%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscene%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscenes%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baway%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhome%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsong%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bline%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btheme%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btaken%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstills%20from%20the%20movie%3B%2Cc0) from 2000 shows the following. Only "scene(s) in/from the movie" appears in both variations:

- ‪scene **in** the movie   0.0000029659% - ‪scene **from** the movie   0.0000015273%
- ‪scenes **in** the movie  0.0000011581% - ‪scenes **from** the movie  0.0000007526%
- ‪role **in** the movie    0.0000018777%
- ‪character **in** the movie   0.0000019697%
- ‪used **in** the movie    0.0000014398%
- ‪part **in** the movie    0.0000010449%
- ‪as **in** the movie  0.0000010909%
- ‪people **in** the movie  0.0000007086%
- ‪and **in** the movie 0.0000007028%
- ‪was **in** the movie 0.0000008490%
- ‪away **from** the movie    0.0000003020%
- ‪home **from** the movie    0.0000002279%
- ‪song **from** the movie    0.0000003774%
- ‪line **from** the movie    0.0000005185%
- ‪theme **from** the movie   0.0000002659%
- ‪back **from** the movie    0.0000001462%
- ‪taken **from** the movie   0.0000001649%
- ‪stills **from** the movie  0.0000001639%

You can see how "in the movie" applies to the whole movie (scene(s), role, character, part, people), whereas "from the movie" is just a part of the movie (scene(s), song, line, theme, stills).